# MySql JDBC call to stored procedure return too many rows

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures

Here is the stored proc in MySQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE topModels(modelCount INT)
BEGIN
  select brand_name as brandName, 
     model_number as modelNumber, 
     model_description as modelDescription,
     parts 
  from 
  (
     select model_number, model_description, parts  
        ,@rownum := if(@brand=t.brand_name, @rownum, 0) + 1 as rownum
        ,@brand := t.brand_name as brand_name
     from
     (
         select brand_name, model_number, model_description, parts, 
         from model f
         group by brand_name, model_number, model_description
         order by brand_name, sum(sold_count) desc
     ) t
 ) tbl 
 where rownum<=5
END
```

When I open MySQL workbench and do:

```
 CALL topModels(5)
```

it return around 3000 rows, which is correct result.

When I run it from Java:

```
  java.sql.CallableStatement cs  = connection.
      prepareCall("CALL topModels(5)");
  java.sql.ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
```

It returns about 400,000 rows as if it ignores "where rownum<=5" condition.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: MySQL workbench will often limit the resultset size.

Comment: I am aware of that, but this is not the issue. It tells me that it return 3xxx rows and this exactly the number of rows if I run count(*) on the whole query

Answer (score 1):

I see that your procedure has `modelCount` but you never use it.

IIRC MySQL does not have `rownum`. Use `LIMIT` instead:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl ... LIMIT " + modelCount.
```

Unfortunately, you can't use procedure param in `LIMIT` (at least not until 5.1).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the JDBC call syntax, something like:

`conn.prepareCall("{call topModels(5)}");`

Comment: If you don't know for sure, this should be a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm completely new to Java JDBC (coming from a .NET camp). However looking at the Oracle documentation. I think you need to pass in parameters separately thus:

```
 java.sql.CallableStatement cs  = connection.prepareCall("CALL topModels(?)");
 cs.setInt(1, 5); // <--  I'm assuming you need set the parameter like this
 java.sql.ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Look this framework (https://code.google.com/p/lindbergframework/). Easy handling of stored procedures and functions, including treatment of cursors automatically.

https://code.google.com/p/lindbergframework/